# ReDocly Output with One Call Per Page?

Tags: swagger, openapi, redoc, redocly

Is it possible to generate output with Redocly or the Redocly CLI that has one request per page? And not all requests in a single, large, scrollable file?

Commands like **redoc-cli bundle -o index.html Sample.yaml** create one file but with all the requests on one page.